# App Engine - Check if incoming email is from Google group member

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-groups, google-groups-api

I'm trying to restrict incoming emails to my app so it only accepts mail from members of a google group. More specifically, I want to only add the contents of the email to my datastore if they are part of the group. I've found the hasMember/IsMember method here: https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/directory/v1/reference/members/hasMember and think this may be what I am looking for, but I do not know how to use it as they haven't provided an example and I'm very new to this.

Would this be the correct API to use for this? Here is my incoming mail handler code, I have added the IF statement comment to show what I would like to do:

```
import webapp2
import logging
from google.appengine.ext.webapp import mail_handlers
from google.appengine.api import mail
import os
from main import WorkRequest
import re


class IncomingMailHandler(mail_handlers.InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        (encoding, payload) = list(message.bodies(content_type='text/plain'))[0]
        body_text = payload.decode()
        logging.info('Received email message from %s, subject "%s": %s' %
                     (message.sender, message.subject, body_text))

        logging.info (message.sender)
        logging.info(message.subject)
        logging.info(body_text)


        #IF MESSAGE_SENDER == MEMBER OF GOOGLE GROUP:

            wr = WorkRequest()

            wr.email = message.sender
            wr.userId = None
            wr.title = message.subject
            wr.content = body_text
            wr.status = "OPEN"
            wr.submission_type = "EMAIL"
            wr.assigned_to = "UNASSIGNED"
            wr.put()

application = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/_ah/mail/.+', IncomingMailHandler)],debug=True)
```